# Get number of Request and response in java

Tags: java, rest

Can anyone suggest me how we can find the no of requests and response send and received in a java code
i have no idea how to get it

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach would be to have some sort of filter/interceptor and increment counter while request is being filtered